# Reusing code in kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

how can I reuse such code in kv lang?

```
<Search_type_panel>:
    max1_optn: max1
    max2_optn: max2
    both_optn: both
    BoxLayout:
        padding: "10dp"
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            CheckBox:
                id: max1
                active: True
                group: 'search_type'
            Label:
                text: "[ref=max1]max1[/ref]"
                size_hint_x: "10"
                markup: True
                on_ref_press: root.setstatus(max1)

            CheckBox:
                id: max2
                active: False
                group: 'search_type'
            Label:
                text: "[ref=max2]max2[/ref]"
                size_hint_x: "10"
                markup: True
                on_ref_press: root.setstatus(max2)
            CheckBox:
                id: both
                active: False
                group: 'search_type'
            Label:
                text: "[ref=both]both[/both]"
                size_hint_x: "10"
                markup: True
                on_ref_press: root.setstatus(max2)
```

As you can see Label and Checkbox can be a grouped composite panel and I have to just supply different parameters to each one, so on the long run maintenance is simple enough, but How do I pass new parameters to these guys? While I know I can group them as:

```
  <custom>:
            CheckBox:
                id: both
                active: False
                group: 'search_type'
            Label:
                text: "[ref=both]both[/both]"
                size_hint_x: "10"
                markup: True
                on_ref_press: root.setstatus(max2)
```

I don't really know how to pass new parameters to the widgets and reuse the kv lang code.

Comment: Why the downvote, just what is irrelevant about this? I don't see a question similar to this so I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reuse code in kv File

### [Dynamic Classes](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes)

Since each *CheckBox* has a different ***active value*** (*True* or *False*), it is not recommended to create a dynamic class containing both *CheckBox* and *Label* because it is difficult to reference the CheckBox and assign different ***id*** and ***active value*** to each of them when it is instantiated as a children.

#### Snippets

```
<Custom>:
    CheckBox:
        active: False
        group: 'search_type'

    Label:
        size_hint_x: "10"
        markup: True
        on_ref_press: app.root.setstatus(self)
```

## Example

The example below creates two dynamice classes for CheckBox and Label respectively.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Search_type_panel(BoxLayout):
    max1_optn = ObjectProperty(None)
    max2_optn = ObjectProperty(None)
    both_optn = ObjectProperty(None)

    def setstatus(self, label):
        print("\nsetstatus:")
        for key in label.refs:
            print("\tUser clicked on refs =", key)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Search_type_panel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustomCheckBox@CheckBox>:
    active: False
    group: 'search_type'

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    size_hint_x: "10"
    markup: True
    on_ref_press: app.root.setstatus(self)

<Search_type_panel>:
    max1_optn: max1
    max2_optn: max2
    both_optn: both

    BoxLayout:
        padding: "10dp"
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            CustomCheckBox:
                id: max1
                active: True
            CustomLabel:
                text: "[ref=max1]max1[/ref]"

            CustomCheckBox:
                id: max2
            CustomLabel:
                text: "[ref=max2]max2[/ref]"

            CustomCheckBox:
                id: both
            CustomLabel:
                text: "[ref=both]both[/ref]"
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - max2 refs clicked]