# Multiple custom widgets with push and pop matrix in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following code for a custom knob widget. I am trying to have 6 of these knobs in a layout. But it doesn't seem to work when I wrap the kv code into a CustomKnob@BoxLayout, I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972588/reusing-code-in-kivy). Is there a way to replicate the kv code to have 6 knobs, each with their own touch area ?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PushMatrix, PopMatrix, Rotate
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

import math

kv = '''
<Dial>
    canvas:
        PushMatrix 
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            origin: self.center    
            
        # red circle        
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0            
        Line: 
            circle: (self.center_x, self.center_y, 112, 0, self.angle)
            width: 5
       
        #green circle        
        Color:
            rgb: .1, 1, .1
        Line:
            width: 2
            circle: (self.center_x, self.center_y, min(self.width, self.height)/ 8.5)
        PopMatrix
        
    Label:
        id: lbl
        text: str(round(root.angle/360,2))
        center: self.parent.center

'''
Builder.load_string(kv)


class Dial(Widget):

    angle = NumericProperty(90)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dial, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        y = (touch.y - self.center[1])
        x = (touch.x - self.center[0])
        temp_calc = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
        if temp_calc >= 0:
            calc = temp_calc
        else:
            calc = 360 + temp_calc
        self.angle = calc
        print(round(self.angle / 360, 2))


class DialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Dial()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DialApp().run()
```

[image: Custom Knob]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a rule for `CustomKnob` in your `kv`:

```
<CustomKnob@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Dial:
        id: d1
    Dial:
        id: d2
    Dial:
        id: d3
    Dial:
        id: d4
    Dial:
        id: d5
    Dial:
        id: d6
```

Then, in your `build()` method:

```
class DialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Factory.CustomKnob()
```

The use of `Factory` is required since `CustomKnob` is defined in `kv`.

Note that you still must work out size and positioning of the `Dials`.